# what is meaning of "\hbox to \hsize" in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, context-mkii

In many tex, I saw `\hbox to \hsize`, such as:

```
{\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
\hfill
\setupframed[height=5cm,offset=.5em,frame=off,backgroundcolor=red]
\framed[width=12cm,align=left]{#1}%
\framed[width=4cm,align=left,leftframe=off]{#2}%
\egroup}
```

I don't know the meaning of the whole box? And what meaning of `to` in it?

Comment: This is low-level TeX-speak used directly alongside the higher-level abstraction. It means, roughly, put the following group in a horizontal box of width `\hsize` (`\hsize` is the TeX dimension describing the width of the text block).

Comment: @PaulGessler, `to` in it is a keyword or other thing?

Comment: Yes, `\hbox to <dim>` will put the following group into a box of width `<dim>`. If `to <dim>` is omitted, the box takes the natural width of the group it encapsulates.

Comment: It's a low level way of saying \makebox[\hsize][l]{...}, more of less.  There are some occasions where \hbox works and \makebox doesn't.

Comment: @JohnKormylo This is ConTeXt: no `\makebox` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compare the different boxes:

```
\starttext
foo\hfill bar

\def\test#1#2{\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
\hfill
\setupframed[height=5cm,offset=.5em,frame=on,backgroundcolor=red]
\framed[width=0.2\hsize,align=left,framecolor=blue]{#1}%
\framed[width=0.29\hsize,align=left,leftframe=off,framecolor=red]{#2}%
\egroup}

\blank
\framed{\test{some more text}{the second argument}}

\def\test#1#2{\hbox to 0.5\hsize \bgroup
\hfill
\setupframed[height=5cm,offset=.5em,frame=on,backgroundcolor=red]
\framed[width=0.2\hsize,align=left,framecolor=blue]{#1}%
\framed[width=0.29\hsize,align=left,leftframe=off,framecolor=red]{#2}%
\egroup}

\framed{\test{some more text}{the second argument}}
\stoptext
```

[image]